# PHP - how to echo all the values of a single column from mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For each row in the `sql` table I want to `echo` out the value in the `post_title` column, I'm very confused as to how this works and nothing I have found online is working.

**My code:**

```
$sql="SELECT post_title FROM posts ORDER BY post_id";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $post_title = $row['post_title'];
    echo '<br>'. $post_title .'</br>';
}
```

It echoes the last 2 rows `post_title` but does not echo the first rows `post_title` (there are only 3 rows/entries)

Any help would be magical, thank you!

Comment: remove the first `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);` outside the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is very clear here.. You are calling `mysqli_fetch_array` multiple times.

`mysqli_fetch_array()` moves the pointer forward each time you call it.

Just remove the first `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);` from code.